# Why dotnet restore creates xprojs for csproj-projects?

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli, dotnet-restore

I have aspnet core project (on full framework), referencing Library.csproj project.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Library": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }  
   }
}
```

Only way I know to restore packages for my webapp is `dotnet restore`. But this creates unwanted Library.xproj.

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
```

fragment.lock contains

```
"Library/1.0.0": {
  "type": "project",
  "framework": ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1",
  "compile": {
    "bin/Debug/Library.dll": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "bin/Debug/Library.dll": {}
  },
  "contentFiles": {
    "bin/Debug/Library.pdb": {
      "buildAction": "None",
      "codeLanguage": "any",
      "copyToOutput": true
    }
  }
},
```

project.lock.json contains

```
"Library/1.0.0": {
  "type": "project",
  "path": "../Library/project.json"
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the community insisted on msbuild support, and adding json support to msbuild was too much of a pain, so the newer versions of .net core will use the xproj.

There may be workarounds, but in a few months everyone will be using the xproj-s anyway, so you're better off learning to live with them.

Comment: So it is fine to have xproj for each csproj commited? Even if this libraries used for nonCore projects also? Where can I read about this? (Not about what will be in future in VS2017, but for current 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Comment: Given that MS made the creation of xproj automatic, yes it's fine. What's also going to happen automatically is the xproj turning into a csproj. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/ Check the roadmap, and also if you're patient, you can hear the guys explaining this here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9HqMZviaMg

Comment: @nikovn: Infact with upcoming VS 2017 Microsoft is moving away from project.json and .xproj. We will be again dealing with .csproj files.

Comment: @nikovn Unfortunately there is only 5 mentions of xproj and none about autogeneration.

Comment: @nikovn VS somehow restores packages without creating this files. I need to reproduce this behaviour on build server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar setup and rely only on: "**nuget restore**" to restore my packages. This seems to work for me and I don't get the xproj files.

Comment: The OP was using `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` which was from before the `.csproj` format was finalized.

Comment: I guess I was bit behind in upgrading myself. This is no longer an issue.